# Google drive button from Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, google-drive-api

I have problems integrating Google Drive button to the Angular 1.5 app https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive. I can successfully add button and show it however when I perform any state change I got an error. Error does not affect any functionality, even button works but error pops up on every state change. I tried to remove button element programatically before state change and then add it again but it didn't helped

[image: Chrome console error]

index.html

```
<script>
    window.___gcfg = {
        parsetags: 'explicit'
    };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

controller.html

```
<div id="container">
<div class="g-savetodrive"
     data-src="/googlelogo.png"
     data-filename="Google.png"
     data-sitename="Google">
</div>
```

controller.js

```
gapi.savetodrive.go('container');
```

Comment: Where are you calling it from local host ?

Comment: Yes. googlelogo.png is on the same domain